# Ansible vars_prompt in separate file

Tags: ansible

Standard variables can be located in separate files by hosts and/or groups.
Eg. group_vars/groupname or host_vars/hostname.

Is it possible to set **vars_prompt** in any other location than in playbook file?
For example ideally directly in group_vars/groupname or group_vars_prompt/groupname?

Didn't find any relevant documentation.
Thanks

Comment: This issue is here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32726 not resolved yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, you can not do that. At best, you could use a dynamic inventory script that calls `read` like so:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
read foo                                                                               
cat <<EOF
{
  "localhost": {
     "hosts": [ "localhost" ]
   },
   "_meta" : {
    "hostvars" : {
      "localhost": {
        "foo": "$foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

But since ansible swallows `STDOUT` and `STDERR` when executing an inventory script (see: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/inventory/script.py#L42), you won't be able to show a question prompt whatever file descriptor you write to.

As an alternative, if you're running under X, you could use Zenity:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
foo=`zenity  --title "Select Host" --entry --text "Enter value for foo"`

cat <<EOF
{
  "localhost": {
     "hosts": [ "localhost" ]
   },
   "_meta" : {
    "hostvars" : {
      "localhost": {
        "foo": "$foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

This way, you'll get a (GUI) prompt.

But I don't think this is desirable anyway, since it can fail in hundred ways. May be you could try an alternate approach, or tell us what you're trying to achieve.

**Alternate approaches**

- use vars files, filled by users or a script
- use ansible `-e` command line options, eventually wrapped in a bash script `read`ing vars, eventually with zenity if you need UI
- let users fill inventory files (`group_vars/whatever` can be a directory, containing multiple files)
- use `lookup` with pipe to read from a script
- use `lookup` with env, to read vars from environment variables
- use Ansible Tower with forms
- use `vars_prompt` (falling back to defaults if nothing is entered), because the playbook is probably the best place to do this
- ...

Any of these solutions is probably better that hacking around inventory which should really be available unattended (because you might run later from Tower, because you might execute from cron, because you might `ansible-pull`, ...).

Comment: Wow, didn't expect the breathtaking answer. Thank you. I was trying to set default Postgres passwd on testing machine, but be able to set custom password on production. Vault is not an option, because the password is stored in password manager shared by multiple users. I will have to rethink the playbook.

Comment: @leucos I am trying to use vars_prompt in a variable file (under host_vars) but ansible does not prompt for any input. Could you please help

Comment: Well @bhavani-prasad, I guess this is what this whole post is all about :)